# How does the Dynasty mechanic work?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

You need a ruler from the same dynasty as another country to be able to form a Personal Union via war.

So how exactly can I raise my chances to get rulers from the same dynasty between me and another country?

Obviously you have to have a royal marriage, but is it pure luck from there or is there anything I can do?

How exactly does the game decide which dynasty a new ruler will belong to?

Answer (score 2):

Having a higher prestige then your royal marriage partners and have a positive relations. When their King/Queen died without a heir then a Noble from your dynasty takes over throne.

Comment: Its mostly a luck based mechanic. The only people who it is remotely reliable for is Austria because they have built in bonuses to it.